# DDR vs DDR2 Tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Should [ddr2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ddr2) be a tag or should we go with something more generic, such as just DDR? I don't know enough about the technical details of DDR version to know if they are technically different enough to deserve their own tag.

What brought on me asking this is [DDR1 Layout Considerations - DOs and DONTs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23208/ddr1-layout-considerations-dos-and-donts) that uses the [ddr2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ddr2) tag even though it is about ddr1.

Comment: Fixed that post's tag ddr2->ddr.

Answer (score 6):

The tag is clearly wrong - The module in use is a LPDDR part, in spite of the title.  Therefore, the tag should be changed.

At this time, we don't have enough questions on this to require separate LPDDR, DDR2, LPDDR2, DDR3, GDDR, etc. tags.  For the time being, then, I think that all questions about double-data-rate busses should receive the [ddr](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ddr) tag.

If we get more of these questions, then we can retag this question [lpddr](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lpddr).

Does everyone agree?